Movie about a model and a bookshop owner
The movie looks to me like it's from the 90s or from the beginning of 2000s.
As I remember it, it happens in Amsterdam, but maybe I'm wrong about. A young girl comes to become a model. There is a scene where she photographs herself with timer on camera, she painted some things on her body, posing nude. Later when she goes to develop photos, she asks a young guy who works there not to look at them while he's developing them.
Also, she discovers a bookshop run by some old man who once was a hippie. There are some scenes in the movie where he remembers his travels through India and some desert, where someone finds him half dead, and there is was girl that fell in love with him etc. Later in the movie it turns out that girl is the model's mother.

Welcome! This reads a bit stream-of-consciousness... could you maybe revisit what you've written and clarify it a bit so that it's more clear?

Sorry, I used what I could remember, I apologise for my english. Luckily, someone posted the answer. (: Enjoy the movie.

Sounds like Snapshots from 2002 with Burt Reynolds, Julie Christie and Carmen Chaplin.

Larry Goldberg is the owner of a second-hand bookstore in Amsterdam. He came to The Netherlands 30 years ago. He's a middle aged hermit who likes to talk and has an answer to everything. [...] One day, a girl walks into his store, who looks like Larry's lost love from Morocco. The girl makes Larry rethink his life. [...] the movie also travels to Morocco, to see Larry and his love 30 years before, and to the United States, where Aïsha's family lives. 

She turns out to be the daughter of the girl he loved in Morocco. Here's the poster:


Thank you very much! Been looking for it for a long time, google did not help me at all. :D

@Seraphim No problem. :) Don't forget to approve the answer by clicking on the check mark.

Done that, thank you, again. (:
